# Remove object from Firebase using AngularFire 2

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I am trying to create a delete function that will get the delete my object from the Firebase.

I have the following structure on FireBase:

```
recipes   recipebooks      recipesPerRecipebook
  - id          - id        - recipebook_id
  - id          - id           - recipe_id: true
```

What I want to do is when I click delete I want to remove the `recipe_id` from `recipes` and the remove it also from  `recipesPerRecipebook/${recipebook_id}`

I created a function in my **recipes.service.ts**

```
deleteRecipe(recipe_id:string, recipebook_id:string) {
    this.sdkDb.child('recipes').remove(recipe_id)
      .then(
        () => alert('recipe deletion requested !')
      );

    this.sdkDb.child('recipesPerRecipebook/${recipebook_id}').remove(recipe_id)
      .then(
        () => alert('recipe Association deletion requested !')
      );
  }
```

I then have this in **recipeDetails.component.ts**

```
delete() {
    this.recipesService.deleteRecipe(this.recipe.$key, this.recipe.recipebook_id);
  }
```

I get the following error:

`error_handler.js:54 Error: Firebase.remove failed: first argument must be a valid function.`

I have two questions, firstly and most importantly where am I going wrong. And secondly doing `this.sdkdb.child(...` twice feels a bit wrong and cumbersome could I simplify this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks quite odd.

Please take a look at the official docs: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/2-retrieving-data-as-objects.md#deleting-data

So you should be able to delete an object like this:

```js
af.database.object('/--your-list-name--/--your-obejct-key--').remove();
```

where `af` is the injected AngularFire2 service.

Comment: The link in your answer is dead. Could you replace it with a working link?

Comment: Behavior completly changed in newer versions.. see here: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md#manipulating-documents

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that's not how `remove` should be called.

If you look at the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#remove), you will see that `remove` takes an optional callback.

So you would have to call it something like this:

```
deleteRecipe(recipe_id:string, recipebook_id:string) {

  this.sdkDb.child(`recipes/${recipe_id}`)
    .remove()
    .then(() => alert('recipe deletion requested !'));

  this.sdkDb.child(`recipesPerRecipebook/${recipebook_id}/${recipe_id}`)
    .remove()
    .then(() => alert('recipe Association deletion requested !'));
}
```

Also, in your snippet, your are not using back ticks for the second path, so `${recipebook_id}` won't be evaluated and replaced.

If you want to remove the two paths in a single operations, you can use [`update`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#update):

```
deleteRecipe(recipe_id:string, recipebook_id:string) {

  this.sdkDb.update({
    `recipes/${recipe_id}`: null,
    `recipesPerRecipebook/${recipebook_id}/${recipe_id}`: null
  })
  .then(() => alert('deleted!'));
}
```

You might also want to consider returning the promise from `deleteRecipe` so that the caller can be informed of the deletion completing.